# full page not accessible

Tags: web-scraping

I have scraped following page my problem is that I want to redirect my code to desired page . I get the page but its not fully loaded contain many missing information why is that?

here is the code

```
    include("admin/LIB_http.php");
    include("admin/LIB_parse.php");
    include("admin/LIB_resolve_addresses.php");
    include("admin/LIB_http_codes.php");
    include("admin/database.php");


$action = "http://domestic-air-tickets.expedia.co.in/flights/initiate-booking";
$method="GET";                                    // GET method
$ref = "http://domestic-air-tickets.expedia.co.in/flights/results?from=DEL&to=HYD&depart_date=25/08/2012&adults=2&childs=0&infants=0&dep_time=0&class=Economy&airline=&carrier=&x=57&y=16&flexi_search=no ";   
                                    // Referer variable
$data_array['rnd_one'] = "O";  
$data_array['from'] = "DEL";  
$data_array['to'] = "HYD";  
$data_array['depart_date'] = "25/08/2012";  
$data_array['adults'] = "2";  
$data_array['childs'] = "0";
$data_array['dep_time'] = "0";    
$data_array['class'] = "Economy";    
$data_array['airline'] ="";    
$data_array['carrier'] = "";    
$data_array['timestamp'] = "1345783916448";    
$data_array['companyid'] = "110342";  
$data_array['source'] = "WL";  
$data_array['BIZ_ACTION_MODE'] = "VIEW_ORDER_CAPTURE";  
$data_array['topLevelRateRules'] = '{"cc":{"df":{"pg":{"f":250.0}}},"dc":{"df":{"pg":{"f":250.0}}},"nb":{"df":{"pg":{"f":250.0}}},"kc":{"df":{"pg":{"f":250.0}}},"ca":{"df":{"pg":{"f":250.0}}},"tax":{"CC":0.0, "DC":0.0, "NB":0.0, "KC":0.0, "CA":0.0}}';  
$data_array['emiJson'] = "{}";  
$data_array['out_no_legs'] = "1";  
$data_array['out_base_price'] = "8860";  
$data_array['out_adult_base'] = "8860";  
$data_array['out_taxes'] = "7678";  
$data_array['out_disc'] = "0";  
$data_array['out_price'] = "16538";  
$data_array['out_fare_key'] = "supp_INDIGO|si-90efea02-d16b-4cec-808a-3d79792ea2b2|fk_6E_311_1345859400000_E0DELHYD_true_";  
$data_array['out_leg_aircode_1'] = "6E";  
$data_array['out_leg_from_1'] = "DEL";  
$data_array['out_leg_fromCityName_1'] = "New Delhi";  
$data_array['out_leg_fromAirportName_1'] = "Indira Gandhi Airport";  
$data_array['out_leg_to_1'] = "HYD";  
$data_array['out_leg_toCityName_1'] = "Hyderabad";  
$data_array['out_leg_toAirportName_1'] = "Rajiv Gandhi International";  
$data_array['out_leg_via_1'] = "n";   
$data_array['out_leg_departs_date_1'] = "25/08/2012";   
$data_array['out_leg_flt_num_1'] = "311";   
$data_array['out_leg_arrives_date_1'] = "25/08/2012";   
$data_array['out_leg_fare_basis_1'] = "E0DELHYD";   
$data_array['out_leg_fare_class_1'] = "supp_INDIGO|si-90efea02-d16b-4cec-808a-3d79792ea2b2|";   
$data_array['out_leg_cabin_type_1'] = "E";   
$data_array['out_leg_refundable_1'] = "R";   
$data_array['out_leg_oa_1'] = "";   

$data_array['out_leg_arrives_1'] = "09:20"; 
$data_array['out_leg_departs_1'] = "07:20"; 
$data_array['out_leg_stops_1'] = "0"; 
$data_array['out_leg_departure_terminal_1'] = "Terminal 1D"; 
$data_array['ts'] = "10135741"; 
$data_array['fromCityName'] = "New Delhi"; 
$data_array['toCityName'] = "Hyderabad"; 
$response = http($target=$action, $ref, $method, $data_array, EXCL_HEAD);   

print_r($response);
```

I can't upload images other wise u can see how page is different from original site page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it by var_dump the $response and then explode to get required URL